# Compile error while implementing IDbSet

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to implement the `IDbSet<>` interface for a specific object type, but I am getting a seemingly inescapable error when trying to implement `IDbSet<>.Create<TDerivedEntity>()`. The code best explains the problem:

```
class ProductSet : IDbSet<Product>
{
    public TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>() where TDerivedEntity : class, Product
    {
    }
}
```

This produces the error

```
Cannot specify both a constraint class and the ‘class’ or ‘struct’ constraint"
```

If I remove the **class** constraint, I get this error:

```
The constraints for type parameter 'TDerivedEntity' of method 'TestEf.ProductSet.Create<TDerivedEntity>()' must match the constraints for type parameter 'TDerivedEntity' of interface method 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<TestEf.Product>.Create<TDerivedEntity>()'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.
```

I did try to use explicit interface implementation and that worked, but what if I don't want to use explicit interface implementation?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why are you implementing `IDbSet` at all? Is EF's own `DbSet` insufficient?

Comment: There are cases when you want to implement it, e.g. unit testing: http://refactorthis.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/mock-faking-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-4-1-with-a-generic-repository/

Comment: In my case, however, I want to implement virtual entities. By virtual entities I mean entities that doesn't exists in database, but are in direct relation to real entities, and it will be great if they can be used the same way other entities and relations are used.

Comment: Alright, that's a fair example, but in that case you won't encounter the problem you're having now, since that example uses a generic implementation. If you go down that road, you would have `MyFakeDbSet<T>` implement `IDbSet<T>` and use `MyFakeDbSet<Product>` (or possibly derive `ProductSet` from that), you wouldn't directly implement `IDbSet<Product>`.

Comment: But that's not going to work... or at least not reliably. It would work in those cases where you start from your virtual set, but it would fall apart as soon as you combine that with managed entities (for lack of a better term)

Comment: The reason is that if you try anything like `from a in context.A where context.B.Any(b => b.Id == a.Id)`, the EF portions that translate the query to SQL will bomb out, if `B` isn't mapped.

Comment: @hvd, thanks for the comments. But I am not planning to derive from Product, so this is why I want to have a non-templated implementation.

Comment: Yes, I know it is going to fail for the Product, so do you know how to fix this problem?! :-) I mean is there anyway to tell EF which classes to translate them to SQL, and which not.

Comment: No, there isn't. You can only get that done by handling it *before* EF sees it, by writing a custom query provider to replace the queries with something EF understands. You'd have to make your IDbSet.Provider return your custom provider, but you'd also have to make the EF-mapped IDbSet.Provider return that same custom provider. This all is a lot more complicated than what I think you've been trying so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found extending IDbSet of T are a lot easier using Extension methods.

As to the actual question:

```
public TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>() where TDerivedEntity : Product, new()
```

should fix it I think.

Comment: That doesn't fix it, I still get the same problem (the second problem), because the constraints are still different.